# Django Unit test is giving Anonymous user while login

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, testcase

I've the below code for Django login Unit test.

```
"""This is the unit test case for form element"""
from django.test import TestCase
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class TestForm(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.credentials = {
            'username': 'abhishek',
            'password': 'Abhishek@12345'}
        User.objects.create_user(**self.credentials)

    def test_login(self):
        # send login data
        response = self.client.post('/accounts/login', self.credentials, follow=True)
        # should be logged in now
        print(response.context['user'])
        self.assertTrue(response.context['user'].is_authenticated)
```

While I'm executing this Unit test through my command python ../manage.py test accounts.tests.test_form.TestForm It's giving the below error.

```
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
AnonymousUser
F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_login (accounts.tests.test_form.TestForm)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Django\webapplication\accounts\tests\test_form.py", line 18, in test_login
    self.assertTrue(response.context['user'].is_authenticated)
AssertionError: False is not true

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 3.391s

FAILED (failures=1)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

This is my login views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, render_to_response
from django.contrib import auth
from accounts.forms import UserAttributeModelForm, UserModelForm

LOG = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def login(request):
    """This is the function to Login authenticated user"""
    LOG.debug("Inside Login function")
    message = ""
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            # correct username and password login the user
            auth.login(request, user)
            return redirect("/crudapplication/show")
        else:
            message = "Error wrong username/password"
    return render(request, 'registration/login.html', {'message': message})
```

Can somebody help me !!!!

Comment: You might want to check the `response` more thoroughly. Did it redirect? e.g. `self.assertRedirects(response, reverse('some_url_pattern'))`. Or did it not redirect and is showing a form with errors? Without your login view, it's hard to tell what's wrong. Best is to use a debugger, set a breakpoint in your test and inspect `response`.

Comment: Where do you create a user?

Comment: @dirkgroten I've pasted my view.py as well...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem when i run the command it creates a temporary DB and create a user in side that db

Comment: `auth.authenticate` might need a `request` as first parameter. But again, use your debugger to check your `response` object.

Comment: @dirkgroten  I did the same...n one thing i debugged....from my unit test file i'm sending a post request. But in views.py when I'm using cond. if request.method == 'POST': then its not going inside  if cond.

Answer (score -2):

replace `self.assertTrue(response.context['user'].is_authenticated)` with `self.assertTrue(response.context['user'].is_active)`

hope this will help you otherwise you can ping me back and i will share the complete test case for the login.